# How to get values on this barplot?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have gone through all the steps which are required to get the values on my bar plot. But I am facing some problems here. Please help me out. Sharing the code and Screeenshot.

**Code:**

ax = sos_df['Status'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10,7),color="coral", fontsize=13);

I am getting the output as below:

[The exact values required for the bar plot I have mentioned are not getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5FTp.png)

Please suggest me something which will help me to get the exact values on the plot. Sharing one reference Picture here.:

[The numbers which are in yellow color is the output I am looking for (Reference Image from google.com)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgssT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ax = sos_df['Status'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10,7),color="coral", fontsize=13)
for a, b in zip(range(len(set(sos_df['Status']))), list(sos_df['Status'].value_counts())):
    plt.text(a, b, str(b), ha='center')
plt.show()
```

I imagine this is what you want... but I can only imagine without any sample data.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Can you please explain the code a bit more so that I will get some idea.

Comment: One more thing. In the above code, for sos_df['Status'], there was only one column which had all the values.

Now the thing is in another example, I have 1 row and 3 columns having values 115,63, and 52. So I have successfully plotted the bar plot for this. But again I want to see the values on the bars of the plot. So share some ideas that will be helpful for me here.

Thank you!!